# AVPlayerItem's stepByCount only smooth for forward, but choppy for backwards?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-capture, avplayer

I have implemented AVPlayerItem's stepByCount method to manually go through a video frame by frame. Here's how it looks like for forward 1 step.

```
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    [player.currentItem stepByCount:1];
```

And backward 1 step

```
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    [player.currentItem stepByCount:-1];
```

The forward 1 step (going forward in time frame by frame) works well. However when I try to go backward frame by frame, it's not as smooth as the forward step. Am I missing something? Or is this because of the way videos are encoded--it's meant to be viewed forward but not backwards--inherently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what encoding format your video is in but compressed videos are encoded with keyframes. These occur either at regular intervals (like once a second) or when the scene changes (like when a cut is made from close up to wide shot). The data between keyframes just describes the cumulative changes since the last keyframe - only pixels that change are noted. As you have deduced, this means that a video in reverse is not how it is designed to be played. When you skip backwards the encoder needs to skip back to the previous keyframe (which could be hundreds or even thousands of frames before your current position) then recreate all the frames up to your required frame before actually presenting you with the composited frame. The only way around this in your situation is to either use an already flattened video format or to flatten it before scanning. You might want to take a look at http://opencv.org/ if you want to get into decompression.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Since each frame of a compressed video contains only the incremental information since the last frame, does this mean when I decompress the video, each frame will contain the full image data instead of the diff, resulting in a huge array of full image frames (and audio tracks of course)? The reason I ask is because I can see that maybe I can just capture image frames in realtime and store them in a huge array of images to play back and forth later, instead of storing them in video format to begin with.

Comment: You could in theory cache them all as they came in but you're talking a load of data to store - for 720p you're talking 30fps at 1280x720 at maybe 24-bits deep which would be about 80mb per second (if my maths is right). You might think of storing the scanned images at a much lower resolution as they will look fine when rewinding and then jumping back to the higher resolution when your scan finishes.

Comment: @amergin I'm working with specific <5 second videos. Is there a way with AVFoundation to make the stepping backward smoother for such short videos where the decoding might not need to be on demand? We're trying to use videos instead of gifs because they're significantly smaller and higher resolution. But not being able to reverse frame by frame is ruining our hope.

Comment: Sorry Ryan, I'm not sure, haven't worked with this stuff for a while. If your videos are small then maybe just decompress them then work on the decompressed data yourself, bit more long-winded than ready made calls though.

Comment: @amergin Do you know if AVFoundation has support for manually managing the data like that? or would that require dropping to lower level frameworks?

Comment: As i said Ryan, I haven't worked on this stuff for a while so I'm afraid I don't remember. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

You can check to see if the AVPlayerItem supports stepping:

```
if (playerItem.canStepBackward)
{
    [playerItem stepByCount:numberOfFrames];
}
else
{
    // Do our best here...
    [player seekToTime:CMTimeSubtract(player.currentTime, CMTimeMake(ABS(numberOfFrames)*1000, compositionFPS*1000)) toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
}
```

Comment: Is there a list of video formats that support stepping?